# Написать подобие своей консоли на Java

Tags: java, консоль

Возникла задача написать что-то на подобии консоли на Java. Чисто для вывода в нее информации. Предполагается что будет текстовое поле, которое к примеру должно содержать 15 строк текста, и в нее построчно что-бы выводились сообщения.
Но если допустим строк в консоли стало больше 15, то последнюю удаляем.
Не пойму как бы это реализовать.

В голове есть идея использовать ArrayList, куда будут попадать сообщения. Если сообщений будет больше 15, то первый элемент будем удалять.

Answer (score 1):

Выпив кофе с горьким шоколадом пришел вот к такой реализации. Может кому-то будет полезно.

```
StringBuffer consoleStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
ArrayList<String> consoleStrings = new ArrayList<>();

private void sendMessageToConsole(String message) {
    consoleStrings.add(message);

    if (consoleStrings.size() > 15) {
        consoleStrings.remove(0);
        consoleStringBuffer.clear();
        for (String msg : consoleStrings) {
            consoleStringBuffer.append(msg);
        }
    } else {
        consoleStringBuffer.append(consoleStrings.get(consoleStrings.size() - 1));
    }
    consoleEditText.setText(consoleStringBuffer.toString());
}
```

Comment: `consoleStringBuffer.delete(0, consoleStringBuffer.length())` можно заменить на `consoleStringBuffer.clear()`